# Cannot login to plesk - event though the psa shadow password is correct

Tags: centos

I'm just trying to login again as admin onto an old VPS that I haven't used for a while.

The password I had on file doesn't seem to work anymore.

The strange things are:

- I'm able to ssh onto the server as root with that same password.
- If I display the content of `/etc/psa/.psa.shadow` it's the password I thought it was.
- I can also login to mysql with `mysql -uadmin -pthepassword` fine

But I can't login to Plesk itself via the web interface as admin. It's not showing any error on the login box, i'm just presented with the box again.

There's no error log in /usr/local/psa/admin/logs either.

Plesk version is 9.3.0, on a CentOS 5 server.

Any idea what is going on here?

Or anything I could check that could help troubleshooting this?

**EDIT**: not sure if that helps but both `select * from cp_access;`
and `select * from misc where param='access_policy';` on the psa db return an empty set

**EDIT 2**: `select * from lockout;` is also empty

Answer (score 2):

Well, i'll be damned.. it's a Chrome bug.

I found a bug report for chrome. Tried on firefox and it worked right away..

(ironic that I've tried restarting the server before even trying a different browser :)

Hope this helps someone.

I'm on Chrome 16.0.912.75 mac

The bug report is here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107966